# WebStorm - Node.jS process.env.PWD is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript, webstorm

I'm running a node.js application through WebStorm. The application includes other modules/etc though mechanisms like this;

```
utils = require "#{process.env.PWD}/utils.coffee"
```

When I run my app from the CLI using this command:

```
node server
```

Everything works fine.

When I run the app from within WebStorm, the `PWD` in `process.env.PWD` is undefined and the app crashes.

I've enabled the Node.js Core Library in WebStorm preferences and I'm still having this issue?

What am I doing wrong or what setting am I missing that would make PWD undefined in this instance? Or, is there a workaround?

Comment: what OS are you on? Does the problem persist when running WebStorm from terminal? Also, please check if 'Include parent environment variables' is enabled in your server.js run configuration - press ellipsis button next to 'Environment variables' field and see if this checkbox is ticked

Comment: I'm on OSX 10.11.6. If I run WebStorm from the CLI I still get the same issue. 'Include parent environment variables' is checked as well.

Answer (score 0):

Looks very similar to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-16153, I think we're not setting PWD variable properly, let me see what can be fixed here

Comment: A workaround would be to specify the variable in the Node.js configuration you're using to run the app.